# UICollectionView not working using swift without storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to set up UICollectionView in my view controller. I am created custom cell CVCell.xib. My collection view is not showing up at all. What's missing in my code?

In my viewController.swift file:

`@IBOutlet var collectionViewNew: UICollectionView?`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionViewNew?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CVCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CVCell")
}

 func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(
    collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return 1
}

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 6
}

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CVCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CVCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

        return cell

}
```

Comment: Did you set this controller as the data source of your collection view?

Comment: If you're setting it up without a storyboard, then you shouldn't have an IBOutlet and you should have a UICollectionView initializer

Comment: I created UICollectionView in xib. So i set datasource and delete of collectionview.

Comment: Does enter the datasource methods?